# Sorting files with the same header names using SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a folder with a lot of data files in. I want to be able to loop through the files, look at the headers and sort them into folders if they have the same headers. Is that possible to do in SSIS? If so would anyone be able point me the direction of how to do this?

Comment: what type of files are you looking at.

Comment: Are you trying to sort by the number columns in the headers or the contents?

Comment: I want to group the files into folders when they have all the same headers.

Comment: Why ssis? You could create a small c# application to run through all files, read first line and do something with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to try and explain this as best I can without writing a book as this a multi stepped process that isn't too complex but, might be hard to explain with just test. My apologies but I do not have access to ssdt at the moment so I can not provide images to aid here.

I would use the TextFieldParser class in the VisualBasics.dll. in a script task. This will allow you to read the header from file into a string array. You can then build the string array into a delimited column and load an object variable with a datatable that has been populated with two columns. The first column being the filename and the second being the delimiter headers.

Once you have this variable you can load a sql table with this information. (optional to skip if you want to load the columns directly into sql as you read them. your call)

Once you have your sql table you can create an enumerator for that dataset based on the unique headers column.

Then use a foreach loop task with script task to enumerate thru the unique header sets. Use a sql task to assign the file names that belong to the unique header set.

Within the script loop thru the returned file names and apply the necessary logic to move the files to there respective folders.

This is sort of a high level overview as I am assuming you are familiar enough with SSIS to understand the steps necessary to complete each step. If not then I would be able to elaborate later in the day when I am able to get to my SSIS rig.

Comment: wow, thanks for such a detailed reply. I will have a go, I am familiar with most of those things. I will give it a shot.

Comment: Not a problem. Just let me know if you have any issues with the process